# Spring validator for REST api works only partially

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-validator

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE. I am trying to validate Spring Boot REST api with *org.springframework.validation.Validator*. 
Spring validator has several approaches to validate entities, so when I am calling

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "id", "field.required");
```

Everything works fine and request fails with validation error but when further I perform different validation

```
if (!StringUtils.isAllLowerCase(request.getId())) {
  errors.rejectValue("id", "Id should be lowercase");
}
```

nothing happens although code is actually executed and *rejectValue*  method is actually called but processing of the request for some reasons is not stopped.

So the question is why validation does not happen and maybe there are different ways to perform validation via Spring/Spring-Boot. I have lots of complicated validation so I try to avoid using JSR-303 and create tons of custom annotations.

**RequestValidator**

```
import com.user.model.TenantRequest;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class TenantRequestValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return TenantRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "id", "field.required");

    TenantRequest request = (TenantRequest) target;

    if (!StringUtils.isAllLowerCase(request.getId())) {
      errors.rejectValue("id", "Id should be lowercase");
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Show your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide details about TenantRequest.java

May be for now you can try to remove @Component as it is not needed because you  are implementing Validator.

Refer my working sample created https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmutha-SpringFormUIValidation/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rcmutha/SpringInputValidation/EmployeeFormValidator.java

Also did you add below in controller ?

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new EmployeeFormValidator());
}
```